# Make pervious and next buttons to loop in Jquery galley

Tags: jquery, for-loop, append, increment, image-gallery

I have the following image gallery in a loop that increments a number after each .imageclass class.

```
<?php 
$array = array(
    $productNumber = 1); ?>

<div class="collection-img-wrap">
<?php 
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'product', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'category_name'=>'Collection', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>
 
<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>


    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>


<div class="collection-img collection-img<?php echo $productNumber++; ?>">

<?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

<div class="col-featured-img" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>');>
</div>

</div><!--collection-img-->


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
 
<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

</div><!--collection-img-wrap-->
```

I'm trying to create previous and next buttons to add and subtract the number 1 to scroll through images.How would I go about doing this?

I created the following code for a next button when clicked hides all .imageclass and shows the next .imageclass with an increment of 1 but it's not working for me. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
for(let y = 1; y <= 50; y++){
$('#next').click(function() {
  $('.imageclass').hide();  
  $('.imageclass'.append(y+1)).show();

});
    }
```

Comment: can you add a working snippet here, would help addressing your issue.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman Thanks for the response. I edited my original post and added a snippet. Let me know your thoughts. Thanks in advance.